# error A2023 instruction operand must have size with LGDT instruction

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, bootloader, osdev

I'm having this error mentioned above in the following assembly code and I couldn't find much on the net too regarding this error code.

```
mov  ax,main_data
mov  ds,ax
mov  bx,gdt_info
lgdt [bx]

main_data segment use16
gdt_start:
c32_gdt GDT <0,0,0,0,0,0>
d32_gdt GDT <0,0,0,0,0,0>

gdt_info:
    dw gdt_info - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

main_data ends
```

Comment: That's odd, LGDT doesn't have a choice of operand-size.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt shows that the memory operand in 16 or 32-bit mode is fixed at `m16&32` (i.e. 48 bits = 6 bytes).  If this is MASM, try using `lgdt [gdt_info]` to let the symbol imply the operand-size.

Comment: Does your assembler need `mov  ax,@main_data` to get a segment-base as an immediate?  Normally in MASM, `mov  ax, symbol` is a load.  Anyway, I assume the linker error is a separate problem.  You should tag this question with what assembler you're using.  (MASM or TASM, and I don't know if this requirement to specify operand size is specific to one or the other.)

Comment: there was no linker error, that was me being dumb.

Comment: @Peter, there is a difference between 16 and 32 bit operand sizes even though the operand is six bytes in both cases. It’s explained in the third and fourth sentences in the first paragraph of the reference you linked.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working need to specify the pointer size by `fword`
gdt register is 48bits or 6 bytes in size so to get it working:
`lgdt fword ptr [bx]`